# How can I define a constructor in an open generic type?

Tags: c#, generics, constructor

I am trying to create on open generic type that has a constructor to be used by derived types, but I either don't know how to do it or it is not possible -- not sure which.

```
 public struct DataType<T> : IDataType {

    private T myValue;
    private TypeState myState;

    internal DataType<T>(T initialValue, TypeState state) {
        myValue = initialValue;
        myState = state;
    }
 }
```

Any help much appreciated!

Cort

EDIT:  the constructor was originally posted as private, which was in error and should have been protected.  BUT -- protected is not allowed in a struct, so I changed it to internal.

Comment: Maybe if the constructor wasn't private it would work...

Comment: If it's to be used by derived types, consider making it `protected` ;-)

Comment: Thanks -- missed that -- am trying to refactor something that exists to use an open generic type as base for common implementation and it was private in the original.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The constructor doesn't have a generic argument, just like any normal method of the class which can use `T` but isn't generic either.

```
public class DataType<T> : IDataType {

    private T myValue;
    private TypeState myState;

    protected DataType(T initialValue, TypeState state) {
        myValue = initialValue;
        myState = state;
    }
 }
```

Note that structs cannot be inherited, and private constructors cannot be called by inheriting classes. Change those two as well in order to get it working.

Comment: I tried this, but get this compiler error: Type 'DataType<...>' in interface list is not an interface

Comment: @Cort: are you sure you didn't make a mistake copying this? The interface list here contains no `DataType<...>`, only `IDataType`. Maybe it's in one of your derived classes?

Comment: You are correct -- it was in another class -- sorry.  Here is the class that is causing that compiler error:      public struct NumberType : DataType<Int32> {

 
    }

Comment: Lucero's answer is still correct. You are trying to inherit from a `struct` and that is not allowed.

Comment: @Cort: the problem is that structs cannot inherit from anything. They can only implement interfaces. Either you change NumberType to a class, or you'll have to rethink your design...

Comment: Ah -- thanks!  That was the key I was missing.  Much appreciated!

Comment: @Martinho -- even though having NumberType as a class was not what I wanted, I did try to change my test code for that and found that I could not extend the struct since it is essentially sealed.  I didn't think a class could extend a struct, but had to try.  I do realize that if I changed both DataType and NumberType to class -- it would work.  Thanks for clarifying why for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
private DataType(T initialValue, TypeState state)
{
     myValue = initialValue;
     myState = state;
}
```